# Change One2many field according to value of a Many2one field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have a One2many field that depends on the value of a Many2one field in the form. The related model for the One2many field depends upon the value of the Many2one field.

```
i_name = fields.Many2one('mod.items',string="Item")
i_fields = fields.One2many('mod.x_fields','field_name',string="Item Characteristics")
```

Here, the 'mod.x_fields' (model name) should vary according to the i_name field value. Is it possible to make such a field? Can this be done using api.onchange?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put @api.onchange in mod.x_fields model and update your field according to your parent model access like self.field_name.i_name

Comment: How do i refer to the model name in the field, inside the @api.onchange?

Comment: the 'mod.x_fields' can be any model. what does self.field_name.i_name do?

Comment: self(current model-mod.x_fields)
self.field_name(model which has those fields i_name and  i_fields)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i had to do it. I had to use reference field for i_name and give the model names as selection options. As given [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=QrZTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=reference+field+dynamic+models+odoo&source=bl&ots=wkhwPmc-cA&sig=ACfU3U27NfHZcpna-6v8A03JbEeT5s4LBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidsey0_-XjAhVS6nMBHbHFADkQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ).Though this answer is different from what i wanted(the question), this is the nearest i got.

```
i_name = fields.Reference(selection='_referencable_models',string='Item')

 @api.model
 def _referencable_models(self):
     return [('mod.item1_fields', 'Item 1'),('mod.item2_fields','Item 2'),...]
```